# Why does including the freetype header files in my C header file produce an error, but can be included in the .c file?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, compilation

Below is an engine_text.h file where I'm attempting to include the FreeType libraries. I want to include the libraries in this header file so that I can define the struct which can be used in other project files.

```
#ifndef H_ENGINE_TEXT
#define H_ENGINE_TEXT

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

typedef struct
EngineFont
{

    FT_Library Library;
    FT_Face Face;

} EngineFont;

void
LoadFont(char* FontPath);

#endif
```

However, when attempting to compile this, I get the following errors from the Visual Studio cl.exe compiler:

```
engine_main.c
h:\Engine\code\freetype/freetype.h(947): error C2208: 'FT_Face_InternalRec_ *': no members defined using this type
h:\Engine\code\freetype/freetype.h(1317): error C2208: 'FT_Size_InternalRec_ *': no members defined using this type
h:\Engine\code\freetype/freetype.h(1549): error C2208: 'FT_Slot_InternalRec_ *': no members defined using this type
```

Note that the error is coming from engine_main.c because it is including the engine_text.h header file. Now for whatever reason, if I place the FreeType includes in the engine_text.c file rather than the header, the program compiles and runs without issue. But of course then I cannot define the struct, which is necessary for me to do.

engine_main.c looks like this:

```
#include "engine_main.h"

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "engine_sdl.h"
#include "engine_shader.h"
// The problematic one:
#include "engine_text.h"
```

Why is it that when the includes are made in another header file it causes so many issues? I'm also not very sure what the C2208 error is really indicating to me.

Comment: can you please provide `engine_main.c` in the variant where it compiles?

Comment: I've added engine_main.c above. @StephanLechner

Comment: This is the version that does not work, right? How does `engine_main.c` look like in the variant where it works?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood what you meant. engine_main.c looks the same in the one that works. In the variant that works, the 2 include statements from the engine_text.c file are placed in the engine_text.h file instead (and thus the EngineFont struct has to be removed).

Comment: so you don't have any version where the EngineFont struct works, right?

Comment: I don't have FT installed, so I need your help to figure it out; I'll open an answer such that I have more space...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the types FT_Library and FT_Face do not behave as intended; but by packing it into a `struct`, the "real" problem might be covered by the C2208-thing, which just indicates that you define a struct without members (misleading, I think).

Just for finding out things, try the following `engine_main.c`:

```
#include "engine_main.h"

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "engine_sdl.h"
#include "engine_shader.h"

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

FT_Library Library;
FT_Face Face;
```

and see if these declarations work. Then let's go the next steps.

Comment: I am receiving the same C2208 error when I changed engine_main.c to this variant.

Comment: And you have removed your EngineFont struct?

Comment: Then the problem lies in the FT_Library itself. Do you have any minimal program using FT_Library that worked, without all the effort in structs and so on that you have done? Probably any example coming together with the library?

Comment: If I isolate the FT code to engine_text.c ONLY, I can get a small simple program to run and work. Here is an example:

Comment: Couldn't get the formatting to work, so I threw it in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/rbKHHx3K

Comment: If you define variables FT_Library and FT_Face globally (as in http://pastebin.com/2ZW7cAvc), does it work then?

Comment: It still works when the variables are defined globally.